# Rails - controller action name to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, function

I have a Rails question.

How do I get a controller action's name inside the controller action?

For example, instead of

```
def create
  logger.info("create")
end
```

I want to write something like

```
def create
  logger.info(this_def_name)
end
```

What is a way to get `this_def_name`?

Answer (score 366, accepted):

**Rails 2.X**: `@controller.action_name`

**Rails 3.1.X**: `controller.action_name`, `action_name`

**Rails 3.2+**: `action_name` (still works in Rails 7)

Comment: Or 'controller.action_name' in Rails 3.0. This is the best way to access the action name in the view.

Comment: If you want to use this in a `before_filter` with a block, do `before_filter { |controller| ... }`.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669663/rails-before-filter-and-action-identification

Comment: FYI, `action_name` works in Rails 3.2.13, and `controller.action_name` doesn't.

Comment: rails 2.3.XX and @controller.action_name does not work, you must use just action_name for this version(s).

Comment: Is there a symbol version?

Comment: FYI `action_name` works in Rails 7.0.x still.

Answer (score 36):

In the specific case of a Rails action (as opposed to the general case of getting the current method name) you can use `params[:action]`

Alternatively you might want to look into customising the Rails log format so that the action/method name is included by the format rather than it being in your log message.

Comment: You used to be able to get the current action by calling action_name, I'm not sure if that still works, but I always thought it was a bit nicer than querying the params.

Comment: Just to clarify, it's "controller.action_name" or "params[:action]", so you might do <% if controller.action_name == 'new' %> in the view. It works for me in Rails 3.2.

Comment: You can also get the controller name via params[:controller]

Comment: `action_name == 'new'` (unprefixed) still works for me in Rails 3.2

Answer (score 20):

controller name:

```
<%= controller.controller_name %>
```

return => 'users'

action name:

```
<%= controller.action_name %>
```

return => 'show'

id:

```
<%= ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path(request.url)[:id] %>
```

return => '23'

Answer (score 8):

This snippet works for Rails 3

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController

  def summary
    logger.debug self.class.to_s + "." + self.action_name
  end

end
```

will print

> . . .
>  
>   ReportsController.summary
>  
>   . . .

Answer (score 3):

mikej's answer was very precise and helpful, but the the thing i also wanted to know was how to get current method name in rails.

found out it's possible with self.current_method

easily found at http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/75258

Answer (score -1):

You can get the Action Name like this

Controller Method

```
def abc

   params[:action] #you can store this any variable or you can directly compare them.

   ab == params[:action] 
 
end
```

This supports from rails 4 to rails 6 versions.

Comment: `params[:action]` this method is already answered by other members.  Your codeblock is not clear either, what's `ab` in there ?

Answer (score -4):

I just did the same. I did it in helper controller, my code is:

```
def get_controller_name
  controller_name    
end


def get_action_name
  action_name   
end
```

These methods will return current contoller and action name. Hope it helps

Comment: Confusing. Why wrap `controller_name`, which is a method that returns the name of the current controller, in another method that just *calls* `controller_name`? Why not just call `controller_name` and be done with it?