# Rails before_filter and action identification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, before-filter

I want to write a before_filter in my controller to identify the action which will execute next. This is for authorization purposes (this is somewhat like role_requirement plugin do..)

Ex: if a user types this url `http://localhost:3000/users`, default it goes to users/index action. And in my users controller i'm having a before filter method say 'check_permission' and i want that method to get 'index' as the action.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `action_name` method on the controller should give you what you're looking for. It's not documented, though, so there is no guarantee it won't disappear someday.

```
before_filter { |controller| logger.debug "Running before the #{controller.action_name} action" }
```

Comment: thanks Steve, surly looks promising I'll check it out 

cheers,
sameera

Comment: The method is still available in rails 3.2, but still undocumented.