# Rails method to return current "controller#action"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Instead of checking `if controller_name == 'foo' && action_name == 'bar'`, is there a Rails method to return the two in the same format that you'd define them in the routes.rb file (`get '/buzz' => 'foo#bar'`)?

Is there something like `get_current_route()` that'll return `"foo#bar"`?

Comment: That format is pretty much unique to the routing system and isn't used elsewhere, and even then it's just a shorthand for two slightly longer options. What's the use case here?

Comment: Avoiding this: `if (controller_name == 'foo' && action_name == 'bar') || (controller_name == 'foo2' && action_name == 'bar2')`

Comment: Make a look-up table: `MAGIC_ROUTES = [ %w[ foo bar ], %w[ foo2 bar2 ] ]` and then `MAGIC_ROUTES.include?([ params[:controller], params[:action] ])`

Comment: @tadman This sounds like a painful way to maintain a duplicated list of routes

Comment: It sounds painful that you've got duplicated routes. Is there any reason why you're concerned about the originating route?

Answer (score 2):

You can get names of your current controller and action by using `controller_name` and `action_name` methods. So you can concatenate strings to get desired result.

Also you can get these values from params hash its considered as a bad practise to do so.

> The params hash will always contain the :controller and :action keys,
>   but you should use the methods controller_name and action_name instead
>   to access these values

[ActionController Parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#routing-parameters)

Reference links:

[Rails - controller action name to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244921/rails-controller-action-name-to-string)

[Can I get the name of the current controller in the view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757491/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-current-controller-in-the-view)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of one.

But you can always write your own and stick it somewhere convenient:

e.g.:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def get_current_route
    "#{params[:controller]}##{params[:action]}"
  end

end
```